# Adding URL hash to Isotope combined filters with checkboxes

Tags: javascript, url, hash, jquery-isotope

Need help with adding URL hash to Isotope.js combined filters. Here is the pen https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/btFfG. I want multiple filters with their own URL Hash. So I would like to get the following URL structure: https://s.codepen.io/desandro/debug/btFfG#brand=.brand1&type=.type3&color=.red&size=.uk-size9

Any ideas?

```
      var $container;
      var filters = {};

      $(function(){

        $container = $('#container');

        createContent();

        var $filterDisplay = $('#filter-display');

        $container.isotope();
        // do stuff when checkbox change
        $('#options').on( 'change', function( jQEvent ) {
          var $checkbox = $( jQEvent.target );
          manageCheckbox( $checkbox );

          var comboFilter = getComboFilter( filters );

          $container.isotope({ filter: comboFilter });

          $filterDisplay.text( comboFilter );
        });

      });


      var data = {
        brands: 'brand1 brand2 brand3 brand4'.split(' '),
        productTypes: 'type1 type2 type3 type4'.split(' '),
        colors: 'red blue yellow green'.split(' '),
        sizes: 'uk-size8 uk-size9 uk-size10 uk-size11'.split(' ')
      };

      function createContent() {
        var brand, productType, color, size;
        var items = '';
        // dynamically create content
        for (var i=0, len1 = data.brands.length; i < len1; i++) {
          brand = data.brands[i];
          for (var j=0, len2 = data.productTypes.length; j < len2; j++) {
            productType = data.productTypes[j];
              for (var l=0, len3 = data.colors.length; l < len3; l++) {
              color = data.colors[l];
              for (var k=0, len4 = data.sizes.length; k < len4; k++) {
                size = data.sizes[k];
                var itemHtml = '<div class="item ' + brand + ' ' +
                  productType + ' ' + color + ' ' + size + '">' +
                  '<p>' + brand + '</p>' +
                  '<p>' + productType + '</p>' +
                  '<p>' + size + '</p>' +
                  '</div>';
                  items += itemHtml;
              }
            }
          }
        }

        $container.append( items );
      }


      function getComboFilter( filters ) {
        var i = 0;
        var comboFilters = [];
        var message = [];

        for ( var prop in filters ) {
          message.push( filters[ prop ].join(' ') );
          var filterGroup = filters[ prop ];
          // skip to next filter group if it doesn't have any values
          if ( !filterGroup.length ) {
            continue;
          }
          if ( i === 0 ) {
            // copy to new array
            comboFilters = filterGroup.slice(0);
          } else {
            var filterSelectors = [];
            // copy to fresh array
            var groupCombo = comboFilters.slice(0); // [ A, B ]
            // merge filter Groups
            for (var k=0, len3 = filterGroup.length; k < len3; k++) {
              for (var j=0, len2 = groupCombo.length; j < len2; j++) {
                filterSelectors.push( groupCombo[j] + filterGroup[k] ); // [ 1, 2 ]
              }

            }
            // apply filter selectors to combo filters for next group
            comboFilters = filterSelectors;
          }
          i++;
        }

        var comboFilter = comboFilters.join(', ');
        return comboFilter;
      }

      function manageCheckbox( $checkbox ) {
        var checkbox = $checkbox[0];

        var group = $checkbox.parents('.option-set').attr('data-group');
        // create array for filter group, if not there yet
        var filterGroup = filters[ group ];
        if ( !filterGroup ) {
          filterGroup = filters[ group ] = [];
        }

        var isAll = $checkbox.hasClass('all');
        // reset filter group if the all box was checked
        if ( isAll ) {
          delete filters[ group ];
          if ( !checkbox.checked ) {
            checkbox.checked = 'checked';
          }
        }
        // index of
        var index = $.inArray( checkbox.value, filterGroup );

        if ( checkbox.checked ) {
          var selector = isAll ? 'input' : 'input.all';
          $checkbox.siblings( selector ).removeAttr('checked');


          if ( !isAll && index === -1 ) {
            // add filter to group
            filters[ group ].push( checkbox.value );
          }

        } else if ( !isAll ) {
          // remove filter from group
          filters[ group ].splice( index, 1 );
          // if unchecked the last box, check the all
          if ( !$checkbox.siblings('[checked]').length ) {
            $checkbox.siblings('input.all').attr('checked', 'checked');
          }
        }

      }
```